# Haskell: read input character from console immediately, not after newline

Tags: windows, haskell, io, ghc, buffering

I've tried this:

```
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering 
    c <- getChar
```

but it waits until the enter is pressed, which is not what I want. I want to read the character immediately after user presses it.

I am using ghc v6.12.1 on Windows 7.

EDIT: workaround for me was moving from GHC to WinHugs, which supports this correctly.

Comment: That's not really a good workaround.  The real workaround is to explicitly choose character-buffered IO; by using the getch from the system conio.h.  Artelius' link contains example code for that.

Comment: It's a good workaround if it suits him! Using a different tool which doesn't have the bug makes sense. If you don't need the language features of recent ghc compilers, WinHugs is faster than ghci or winghci in my experience. It works without fuss and looks nicer. You also don't need to `:r` when you've edited your code, which I love.

Comment: How does it relate to `main = do hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering; interact $ map Data.Char.toUpper`? In my case it waits for a new line before any output appears. (Ubuntu, GHC 7.6.3.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Might be a bug:

http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2189

> The following program repeats inputted characters until the escape key is pressed.
>
> ```
> import IO
> import Monad
> import Char
>
> main :: IO ()
> main = do hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
>           inputLoop
>
> inputLoop :: IO ()
> inputLoop = do i <- getContents
>                mapM_ putChar $ takeWhile ((/= 27) . ord) i
> ```
>
> Because of the hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering line it should not be necessary to press the enter key between keystrokes. This program works correctly in WinHugs (sep 2006 version). However, GHC 6.8.2 does not repeat the characters until the enter key is pressed. The problem was reproduced with all GHC executables (ghci, ghc, runghc, runhaskell), using both cmd.exe and command.com on Windows XP Professional...

Answer (score 23):

Yes, it's a bug. Here's a workaround to save folks clicking and scrolling:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
import Data.Char
import Foreign.C.Types
getHiddenChar = fmap (chr.fromEnum) c_getch
foreign import ccall unsafe "conio.h getch"
  c_getch :: IO CInt
```

So you can replace calls to `getChar` with calls to `getHiddenChar`.

Note this is a workaround just for ghc/ghci on Windows. For example, winhugs doesn't have the bug and this code doesn't work in winhugs.

Comment: I like this solution. Note, however, that `unsafe` will cause a blocking call to `getch` to block all other threads in the program. I am author of the [`hidden-char`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hidden-char) package on Hackage which has a variant of this function using the unsafe FFI.

Comment: If you get something similar to this
`ByteCodeLink: can't find label 
During interactive linking, GHCi couldn't find the following symbol: 
    getch`
in GHCi, try `_getch` instead of `getch` for the foreign import.

Source: https://stackoverrun.com/de/q/10551494

Answer (score 4):

Hmm.. Actually I can't see this feature to be a bug. When you read `stdin` that means that you want to work with a "file" and when you turn of buffering you are saying that there is no need  for read buffer. But that doesn't mean that application which is emulating that "file" should not use write buffer. For linux if your terminal is in "icanon" mode it doesn't send any input  until some special event will occur (like Enter pressed or Ctrl+D). Probably console in Windows have some similar modes.

Comment: Thank you. Sounds truthfully, but if you see the bug description: it is really exaclty what I was asking, so for now I am going to mark answer of Artelius.

Comment: At least it works differently under Windows ans Linux. Under linux the code posted by Steves works WITHOUT waiting. So I think it's a bug, and should be fixed.

Comment: This is (partially) incorrect. When using Console Emulation Software, or the MinGW console, buffering is still ignored. Windows ignores buffering at OS level, not at console level.

Answer (score 4):

The [Haskeline](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskeline/0.6.2.2/doc/html/System-Console-Haskeline.html) package worked for me.

If you need it for individual characters, then just change the sample slightly.

1. `getInputLine` becomes `getInputChar`
2. `"quit"` becomes `'q'`
3. `++ input` becomes `++ [input]`

```hs
main = runInputT defaultSettings loop
    where 
        loop :: InputT IO ()
        loop = do
            minput <- getInputChar "% "
            case minput of
                Nothing -> return ()
                Just 'q' -> return ()
                Just input -> do outputStrLn $ "Input was: " ++ [input]
                                 loop
```

Answer (score 0):

From [comment of @Richard Cook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983974/haskell-read-input-character-from-console-immediately-not-after-newline#comment77416033_13370293):

Use [hidden-char: Provides cross-platform getHiddenChar function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hidden-char).

Answer (score 0):

I used the [haskeline](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskeline-0.6.2.2/docs/System-Console-Haskeline.html) package, suggested in other answers, to put together this simple alternative to `getChar`. It requests input again in the case that `getInputChar` returns `Nothing`. This worked for me to get past the issue; modify as needed.

```
import System.Console.Haskeline
  ( runInputT
  , defaultSettings
  , getInputChar
  )

betterInputChar :: IO Char
betterInputChar = do
  mc <- runInputT defaultSettings (getInputChar "")
  case mc of
    Nothing -> betterInputChar
    (Just c) -> return c
```