# What is a simple way to wait for and then detect keypresses in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io, interactive

I'm pretty new to Haskell, so I'm looking for a simple-ish way to detect keypresses, rather than using `getLine`.

If anyone knows any libraries, or some trick to doing this, it would be great!

And if there is a better place to ask this, please direct me there, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: There is a similar thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983974/haskell-read-input-character-from-console-immediately-not-after-newline

Comment: Most GUI libraries (ex: gtk2hs) have a onKeyPress type operation - if you're doing anything large or for distribution then consider those.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't want blocking you can use `hReady` to detect whether a key has been pressed yet. This is useful for games where you want the program to run and pick up a key press whenever it has happened without pausing the game.

Here's a convenience function I use for this:

```
ifReadyDo :: Handle -> IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
ifReadyDo hnd x = hReady hnd >>= f
   where f True = x >>= return . Just
         f _    = return Nothing
```

Which can be used like this:

```
stdin `ifReadyDo` getChar
```

Returning a `Maybe` that is `Just` if a key was pressed and `Nothing` otherwise.

Comment: I'd also mention about `hSetEcho` function, which allows suppress echoing characters into `stdout`, while using `getChar`.

Answer (score 9):

```
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  x <- getChar
  putStrLn ("You pressed: " ++ [x])
```

I don't know when this is guaranteed to work.  Putting the terminal into a "raw" mode is a system-dependent process.  But it works for me with GHC 6.12.1 on Linux.

Comment: That's the issue I've found, it works rather poorly on Windows, and requires a newline before it is submitted.